# MVVMCross MvxExpandableListView control

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I am trying to implement the `MvxExpandableListView` control using MVVMCross and have not found any example code/implementation anywhere for this control.

Does anyone know of any sample projects using this control? Or perhaps does someone mind sharing an example here?

Comment: What functionality do you need from MvxExpandableListView? Could you use e.g. MvxRecyclerView instead?